# Are Objective-c protocols the same as generics?

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is not about `@protocols`, I think.

I'm very new to iOS. I've tried to search for this, but don't really know what to look for.

The Stanford [CS193P Course](https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-7-apps-for/id733644550) lecture 4 mentions Protocols help inform the compiler of the id type:

```
id <UIScrollViewDelegate> scrollViewDelegate
```

The instructor says that the angle brackets notation (`<>`) designates the protocol, to inform the compiler what to expect.

Is this similar to what Generics do in C#, or is this completely different?

Comment: Protocols are essentially the same as Java "interfaces".  The use of `<>` has nothing to do with generics.

Comment: If you want generics use Swift. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their syntax might look similar but, protocols and generics are completely different concepts. Protocols are similar to interfaces in C#. On the other hand, there is no direct equivalent of a generic in Objective-C, even though type introspection can be used as an alternative.

From Wikipedia:

> Generics allow a type or method to operate on objects of various types
>   while providing compile-time type safety.
>
> A protocol or interface is a common means for unrelated objects to communicate with each other. These are definitions of methods and
>   values which the objects agree upon in order to cooperate.

Comment: Unrelated objects... sort of like the button sending a message to the controller that it was clicked...it also doesn't know what type of controller it is. Or the controller updating a label. Are these the concepts for protocols?

Comment: Your examples are more about the target-action pattern, but they are very similar. Whenever an object needs to let another object know about something, a protocol is a possible option to use. Protocols are widely used in the iOS SDK, so you already have a lot of example use cases.